# Can I delete dot(.) in the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad, soft-keyboard, android-inputtype

there is editText field in my app, and get 8 digit Numbers for get birthDay.
So now it work. but there is .- button in app.

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_birth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/notokr_regular"
        android:hint="@string/text_birthday"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:met_errorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
        app:met_floatingLabelPadding="13dp"
        app:met_floatingLabelTextColor="@color/color_000000"
        app:met_floatingLabelTextSize="14sp"
        app:met_textColor="@color/color_555555"
        app:met_underlineColor="@color/color_e0e0e0" />
```

[image: when keyboard show like this!]

so how can I make not show '.-' button? I want to show only number buttons.
is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

The other symbols will still be displayed on the keyboard, but the user will not be allowed to enter them in the field.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. now in my code not allowed to enter other symbols except number. but I want to not showing other symbols.

Comment: Not possible, as far as I know. You can use one of couple of keyboard layouts. This is so that Android supports custom keyboards

Comment: hmm... if there is not possible, I have to make your way. thank you

Comment: Regretfully, nothing better can be done. Of course an option is not to use `EditText`, but a custom view of your own that shows a custom keyboard of your own (which will actually be your own view with listeners). However, this will be a lot of effort and only do it if you REALLY need this desperately.